# Make jQuery button for Sweetpages

Tags: jquery, button

I'd like to make a button to go back and forth for the paginated display I have here, but im not sure how to incorporate it in the following.. I'm trying to learn JQuery as its getting easier but I still cant figure it out..

If your not sure how the Sweetpages plugin works, here's the code. It already creates nice little buttons at the bottom, which I still want, but I want actual buttons too.

I want buttons with the id of "button_back" and "button_forward" to decipher which way the paginated display moves.. Thank you this site is great!

```
(function($){

// Creating the jQuery plugin:

$.fn.sweetPages = function(opts){

// If no options were passed, create an empty opts object
if(!opts) opts = {};

var resultsPerPage = opts.perPage || 3;

// The plugin works best for unordered lists, althugh ols would do just as well:
var ul = this;
var li = ul.find('li');

li.each(function(){
    // Calculating the height of each li element, and storing it with the data method:
    var el = $(this);
    el.data('height',el.outerHeight(true));
});

// Calculating the total number of pages:
var pagesNumber = Math.ceil(li.length/resultsPerPage);

// If the pages are less than two, do nothing:
if(pagesNumber<2) return this;

// Creating the controls div:
var swControls = $('<div class="swControls">');

for(var i=0;i<pagesNumber;i++)
{
    // Slice a portion of the lis, and wrap it in a swPage div:
    li.slice(i*resultsPerPage,(i+1)*resultsPerPage).wrapAll('<div class="swPage" />');

    // Adding a link to the swControls div:
    swControls.append('<a href="" class="swShowPage">'+(i+1)+'</a>');
}

ul.append(swControls);

var maxHeight = 0;
var totalWidth = 0;

var swPage = ul.find('.swPage');
swPage.each(function(){

    // Looping through all the newly created pages:

    var elem = $(this);

    var tmpHeight = 0;
    elem.find('li').each(function(){tmpHeight+=$(this).data('height');});

    if(tmpHeight>maxHeight)
        maxHeight = tmpHeight;

    totalWidth+=elem.outerWidth();

    elem.css('float','left').width(ul.width());
});

swPage.wrapAll('<div class="swSlider" />');

// Setting the height of the ul to the height of the tallest page:
ul.height(maxHeight);

var swSlider = ul.find('.swSlider');
swSlider.append('<div class="clear" />').width(totalWidth);

var hyperLinks = ul.find('a.swShowPage');

hyperLinks.click(function(e){

    // If one of the control links is clicked, slide the swSlider div 
    // (which contains all the pages) and mark it as active:

    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

    swSlider.stop().animate({'margin-left':-(parseInt($(this).text())-1)*ul.width()},'slow');
    e.preventDefault();
});

// Mark the first link as active the first time this code runs:
hyperLinks.eq(0).addClass('active');

// Center the control div:
swControls.css({
    'left':'50%',
    'margin-left':-swControls.width()/2
});

return this;

}})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function(){
    /* The following code is executed once the DOM is loaded */

// Calling the jQuery plugin and splitting the
// #holder UL into pages of 3 LIs each:

$('#holder').sweetPages({perPage:1});

// The default behaviour of the plugin is to insert the 
// page links in the ul, but we need them in the main container:

var controls = $('.swControls').detach();
controls.appendTo('#main');

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Taking the `swControls div` from [Sweet Pages Demo](http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2010/05/sweet-pages-jquery-pagination-solution/demo.html):

```html
<div class="swControls">
    <a href="" class="swShowPage">1</a>
    <a href="" class="swShowPage active">2</a>
    <a href="" class="swShowPage">3</a>
    <a href="" class="swShowPage">4</a>
    <a href="" class="swShowPage">5</a>
    <a href="" class="swShowPage">6</a>
    <a href="" class="swShowPage">7</a>
</div>
```

You can achieve Back/Forward functionality with something like this:

```js
$('.swControls').prepend('<input type="button" class="swFB" id="button_back" value="Back" />');
$('.swControls').append('<input type="button" class="swFB" id="button_forward" value="Forward" />');

$('.swFB').click( function(){
    var curPage = parseInt($('.swShowPage.active').text(), 10);
    var nextPage = ($(this).attr('id') == "button_back") ? curPage - 1 : curPage + 1;
    $('.swShowPage:contains("' + nextPage + '")').click();
});
```

If you need to place the buttons somewhere else, just modify the first 2 statements accordingly.

**UPDATE:**

Here's a more abstracted version:

```
function swGotoPage(page){
    $('.swShowPage:contains("' + page + '")').click();
}

var baseFB = '<input type="button" class="swFB" />';
var offset = 'pgOffset';
var active = '.swShowPage.active';

var $pgBack = $(baseFB)
    .attr('id', 'button_back')
    .attr('value', "Back")
    .attr(offset, '-1');

var $pgForward = $(baseFB)
    .attr('id', 'button_forward')
    .attr('value', "Forward")
    .attr(offset, '1');

$.each([$pgBack, $pgForward], function(i,$obj){
    $obj.click(function(){
        var nextPage =  parseInt($(active).text(), 10) + parseInt($(this).attr(offset), 10);
        swGotoPage(nextPage);
    });
});

$('.swControls').prepend($pgBack);
$('.swControls').append($pgForward);
```

Comment: How would he place the element without prepend & appending it? Can it be assigned by a div's class?

Comment: @JD-Audi What do you mean? Would the back/forward elements already be in the DOM inside a `div` container?

Answer (score 0):

AutoLoad

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    /* The following code is executed once the DOM is loaded */

    // Calling the jQuery plugin and splitting the
    // #holder UL into pages of 3 LIs each:

    $('#holder').sweetPages({perPage:1});

    // The default behaviour of the plugin is to insert the 
    // page links in the ul, but we need them in the main container:

    var controls = $('.swControls').detach();
    controls.appendTo('#main');

    /* BEGIN New function - Solution */
    function xautoLoadSlider() {
        var curPage = parseInt($('.swShowPage.active').text(), 10);
        var nextPage = ((curPage + 1) > $('.swShowPage').length) ? 1 : curPage + 1;
        $('.swShowPage:contains("' + nextPage + '")').click();      
    }

    var xAutoLoad = setInterval(function() {
        xautoLoadSlider();
    }, 5000);   
    /* END New function - Solution */

});
```